# Different outputs when encode to h265 using CPU only and GPU together

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, h.265

I'm using `ffmpeg` to convert **.mp4,.mkv** files with enconde **h264** to **h265** using **CPU only**, if using **GPU together** will outputs the same as using cpu only?

```
for %%a in (*.mkv, *.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0 -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -crf 18 -preset medium -tune animation "Out\%%~na.mkv"
)
```

Comment: Please add the two commands you use for CPU-only/shared to your question. If you are doing this by changing the codec `-c:v libx265` vs `-c:v hevc_vaapi`, then **no**, the outputs will not be identical

Comment: @Cpt.Whale add the code i'm using

Comment: and what command do you want to use for GPU?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Today I'm not using GPU

Comment: what command do you **want to** use for GPU/shared? for example, `hevc_nvenc`?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale yes, but exist another?

Comment: There are other encoders, but the answer is that **no**, the outputs will not be identical. I'll add some detail in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, changing only the codec/encoder will result in *very* different output by default. Generally, gpu encoders like `hevc_nvenc` will output files with significantly larger file size (and higher bitrates) compared to cpu-only encoders like `libx265`.

Different encoders have different defaults. And different encoders have different abilities. For example, hardware encoders like `hevc_nvenc` do not support Constant Rate Factor (`-crf`) like you specified in your question. If you adjust the settings to get the same size, then the quality will not be the same. And even if you adjust the settings so that the encoders deliver the same size/quality for a particular video, they may not deliver the same size/quality with a different video.

Depending on the codec you choose, ffmpeg has options for bitrate, quality, audio, etc. that you can set to get an output file that is very similar to another encoder's defaults, but not identical.